# Can't Control The Volume In The Activity of Android

Tags: android

I wrote a simple game and I want to control the volume by pressing the button at the side my phone, but it doesn't work. In the code ,you can see the parameter of `setContentView(Layout layid)`is a `View`. I guess it is the reason it didn't work because another class using `setContentView(Layout layid)` worked. Please suggest.

```
package com.mario.load;

import com.mario.menu.MenuActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import game.activity.GameActivity;

public class LoadActivity extends GameActivity  implements Runnable
{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
 {
  new Thread(this).start();

  this.SetScreenToFull();

  this.GetScreenSize();

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  super.setContentView(new LoadView(this));
 }

 @Override
 public void run() 
 {
  LoadResource.LoadImage(this);

  LoadResource.LoadMusic(this);

  Intent i = new Intent(this,MenuActivity.class);
  this.startActivity(i);
  this.finish();
 }

public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
 if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
 {
  this.finish();
 }
 AudioManager mAudioManager = (AudioManager)  getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  

 switch (keyCode) {


 case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
   mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_LOWER,AudioManager.FX_FOCUS_NAVIGATION_UP);    

 return true;

 case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:

 mAudioManager.adjustStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,AudioManager.ADJUST_RAISE, AudioManager.FX_FOCUS_NAVIGATION_UP); 

 return true;

 }
return true;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);`. It's a method of your Activity and remove the onKeyDown method.

Comment: I will try it this afternoon.Thank you.

Comment: Hello,I have tried it with the method you given me.And finally I found the reason that it didn't work was the `view` has rewritten the method  `onKeyDown `.So it didn't work when i rewritten the method `onKeyDown ` because this method was't called.Thanks for your help.